# Discord.js, failed api call

Tags: javascript, arrays, api, discord.js, undefined

I'm trying to make a simple trivia discord bot, i'm fairly new to JavaScript and can't seem to solve the problem.

http://prnt.sc/u7rrbk
this is the code trying to get a question from https://opentdb.com/api_config.php

Not quite sure how to get the data from the array, everything that i've tried so far returns undefined.

this is what shows up in console https://prnt.sc/u7rs33

Answer (score 1):

```js
// since `results` is an array, you should change:
trivia.results.category;

// to:
trivia.results[0].category; // [0] gets first value in array
```

```js
// example:
const obj = {
  results: [{
    something: true
  }]
};

console.log(obj.results.something); // undefined
console.log(obj.results[0].something); // true
```

Comment: ahh ok i wasn't aware that i had to put .results after it since i was only trying console.log(array.results[0])